# Правильно ли построено предложение "Это нам не надо"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Правильно ли построено предложение "**Это нам не надо**"?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, неверно. Сказуемое с частицей НЕ требует родительного падежа:Этого нам не надо.

Comment: Но ведь не всегда требует. А почему в этом случае именно так?

Answer (score 2):

Существительное, относящееся к глаголу с отрицанием, может иметь форму родительного или винительного падежа.
НО! ***Если в качестве зависимого слова используется местоимение, нужен родительный падеж***:  не допущу этого; не делайте того, **не надо**(чего?) **этого**.
[**Какой падеж нужен при отрицании?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr)

***"Нам этого не надо***"( или семейная консультация особенной семьи)
Юрий Газзаев: *"Жалеют слабых. **Этого нам не надо".***
***Нам этого не надо***. Опыта лучше так не набирать», — выразил общее мнение в своем Facebook политолог Айдос Сарым.
***Такого нам не надо***, обойдемся без австралийских сумчатых...

Comment: "Надо" - не глагол (однако является сказуемым)

Answer (score 2):

Можно и так сказать, если предполагается продолжение, например - "а это - всегда пригодится".

Answer (score 1):

В Нацкопусе используются обе формы: **этого не надо, это не надо** (частотность 303:186).

В пользу В.п. говорит конкретность предмета и инверсия 
[§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)

1) При указании на конкретный объект («именно этот предмет, а не вообще какой-то»): *не отрецензировал рукопись, которую ему прислали; не выпила молоко, которое ей оставила мать*. Например: *Он не отвергнул тогда с презрением эти сто рублей* (Достоевский); *Не наклоняй знамя-то...* (Горький);

2) Нередко при инверсии дополнения (постановке его впереди глагола-сказуемого), например: *Журнал я этот не люблю* (Тургенев); *...дверь не притворяла* (Достоевский); *Кулаком правду не убьешь* (Горький); *Трактор им не дали* (Шолохов)

В пользу Р.п. говорит то, что *это* может являться связкой, поэтому предложение читается неясно.

Answer (score 0):

Коряво звучит. Посмотреть бы контекст... *Но хочется исправить на "этого"*. Хотя в отдельных "случаях юмора" прямой речи персонажа — можно.
Например, подруга скривила рожу и удивилась: "Тебе это надо? А нам это надо? Нет, дорогуша, это нам не надо!"